# vim-javacomplete2 - Don't write first suggestion to line

Tags: vim, autocomplete, editor, vim-plugin

I recently installed the plugin vim-javacomplete2 via vim-plug into Vim 7.4. Overall, I am happy with it but there is one thing that bugs me. When i initiate it with `<C-x><C-o>` it writes the first suggestion to the line like so.
[image]

Is there anyway to have it list the suggestions without writing the first one to the line like this?
[image]

I see it done on the plugin's [GitHub page](https://github.com/artur-shaik/vim-javacomplete2) but i am unable to figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it says it uses the vim omnicompletion, i bet it works with the normal completopt settings: `:set completeopt+=noinsert` see `:help completeopt` for more information